# Все ли правильно Я сделал?

Tags: массивы, pascal

Все ли правильно Я сделал ?

ТЗ

- Создает массив из не более чем 100 целых чисел
- Вводит с клавиатуры n целых чисел
- Выводит на экран введённые с клавиатуры числа
- Увеличивает в 3 раза значения каждого элемента массива
- Выводит на экран изменённые значения элементов массива
- Возводит в квадрат каждый элемент массива
- Выводит на экран изменённые значения элементов массива

В программе необходимо использовать процедуру печати элементов массива PECH

```
program Hello;
var PECH: array[1..100] of integer;
n,s,i:integer;
begin
write('Введи n ==>');
readln(n);
for i :=1 to n do
begin
write('PECH[',i,']=');
readln(PECH[i]);
end;
for i :=1 to n do
write(PECH[i],'');
writeln;
for i :=1 to n do
PECH[i]:=PECH[i]*3;
for i :=1 to n do
write(PECH[i],'');
writeln;
for i :=1 to n do
PECH[i]:=PECH[i]*3;
for i :=1 to n do
write(PECH[i],'');
end.
```

Comment: Нет, Вы не все сделали правильно.

Comment: И что Я сделал не так ?

Comment: "Возводит в квадрат каждый элемент массива" - ??

Comment: *Все ли правильно Я сделал ?* - **неправильно написали заголовок**. Вы сами, читая  такое название, поймете, какая задача обсуждается?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Очевидно, что неправильно.

1. Вместо возведения в квадрат умножение на 3.
2. Вторая операция производится с уже изменёнными числами, а не с оригинальными.
3. Я не очень знаю паскаль, но очень похоже, что числа выводятся подряд без пробелов.
4. <s>Некоторое время назад `;` перед `end` не компилировалась. Но это уже поменяли.</s>

И вообще, надо не вопросы задавать, а просто запустить эту штуку и посмотреть, что выводит. Даже онлайн-компилятор типа [ideone](https://ideone.com/) вполне подойдёт, если уж лень ставить на комп нормальный.

Comment: не перед `end` а перед `else`

Comment: @Grundy, при чём тут `else` и что вообще `;` после него делать? Именно перед `end`.

Comment: @Grundy, впрочем, сейчас оба варианта компилируются: https://ideone.com/t3UnoX & https://ideone.com/PX6u1n.

Comment: не после `else`, а **ПЕРЕД** `else`

Comment: Вот про что: https://ideone.com/0UVcXC

Comment: @Grundy, я специально нашёл свою старую прогу на паскале и там нет `;` ни перед одним `end`. А `else` в ней в принципе не оказалось. Видимо фишка в том, что сейчас `;` может означать пустой оператор, поэтому можно их много влепить: https://ideone.com/iI1HFv. Ну а перед else лишнего оператора быть не может, поэтому и ошибка. А вообще паскалевский поход - что она разделитель между операторами, а не завершение оператора, как в других языках. Понятия не имею, где сейчас взять borland pascal. Ну или хотя бы просто какой-то паскаль постарше.

Comment: собственно `;` всегда был пустым оператором